# Windows XP SP3 custom dpi settings

Tags: windows-xp, dpi

I am using 105% (101 DPI) custom DPI settings for easier reading but unfortunately those settings are not fully applied across whole system. Opening Windows Explorer for example applies the newly increased font size correctly, it also works on desktop icons, text, and some other programs. On the other hand some other programs remain at default 100% (96 DPI) like: Utorrent, CCleaner, etc.

I also tested this on Windows 7 and everything works fine. When I increase DPI settings to 105% they are fully applied system wide and also correctly applied to above mentioned programs.

Does anyone have a solution how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the only solution is to use Windows Vista or Windows 7. The feature was introduced in Windows Vista.

Comment: Thank for your answer, i guess. But that doesn't really help me much. I'll search the Internet some more and maybe i'll find a better solution to my problem (if there is a solution, that is). Cheers.